# Emberjs: How to render a view with the view name in variable?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i would like to add some cards to a board, all cards are very different. so i want to create different view for each card that can bind different events and template. I set a 'type' property in the card model which to distinguish the cards.

the board template look like below:

```
{{#each card in cards}}
  {{render card.type card class="card"}}
{{/each}}
```

However, the first argument for the render help can not be a variable, it can only be the card view name string.

anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: I've edited my answer including a working jsbin, have a look

Comment: I just did another edit (edit 2) to the jsbin using also the object's data to be used in the template with {{data}}, now everything is dynamic, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned the built-in `render` helper only accepts a string to lookup the template to render, therefore one possible solution would be to write your own custom `render` helper, which then after getting the correct name with `card.get('type')` delegates the rendering to the built-in `render` helper. This could look something like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('renderCard', function(context, card, options) {
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.render.call(context, card.get('type'), 'card', options);
});
```

After that, you could use it like this in your template:

```
{{#each card in cards}}
  {{renderCard this card}}
{{/each}}
```

#### Edit

I've also added a basic [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/izaduh/3/edit) that shows it working.

#### Edit 2

Edited the jsbin again, using object data to be rendered into the template, [see here](http://jsbin.com/izaduh/6/edit).

#### Edit 3

Lamentably the `DS.FixtureAdapter` does not support `embedded` records which is what you need to make it work. But you could configure you orignal `DS.RESTAdapter` like this:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();

App.Adapter.map('App.Dashboard',
  cards: {embedded: 'always'}
);

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: App.Adapter
});
```

This way the `card` records are `always` loaded with the parent record. I guess doing this change would make the call to `card.get('type')` in you handlebar helper return the value rather then `undefined`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I tried the helper code you given ,but it seems not work when the render call.

Comment: there was a typo in my answer, it's fixed now, sorry :)

Comment: yes, i realise that the context missing in the template. i fixed that, but still get the error message: **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'match'**.  my updated code look like this: `Ember.Handlebars.helper('renderCard', function(context, type, card, options) {
 if (type && card)
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.render.call(context, type, card, options);
});`

Comment: @ZheX your updated code is slightly wrong, if you pass `type` like this you do not get the string that you need, please my updated answer with a working jsbin.

Comment: I viewed your demo code, that is great. but when i used nested card model list (has many), i can not get result of `card.get("type")`, it is alwasy `undefined`.

Comment: yes, you are right. the fixture does not work with embed in data. i have changed my code and it works now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Ember 1.9 solution above doesn't work. Use another way to register helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper 'renderDynamic', (context, model, options)->
  contextString = options.hash.contextString
  model = options.data.view.getStream(model).value()
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.render(model.get('type'), contextString, options)
```

And in the template:

```
= hb 'renderDynamic "this" currentModel contextString="curremtModel"
```

or in handlebars:

```
{{renderDynamic "this" currentModel contextString="curremtModel"}}
```

Comment: at ember 1.13 view.getStream do you know what should we use ? thx