# How to stop Ember Render complaining about deprecated quoteless parameters when using call()?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, view-helpers

I am following a template for dynamically choosing which model, route, controller to render with a render helper, as [outlined in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252471/emberjs-how-to-render-a-view-with-the-view-name-in-variable) (and elsewhere). My problem is that we want to run with the `Ember.ENV.RAISE_ON_DEPRECATION` flag set, to catch problems before they develop into upgrade nightmares. I am calling Ember.Render from a handlebars helper, like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('renderModuleEdit', function(callingContext, module, options) {
  var modelName = callingContext.get('type').get('modelName');
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.render.call(callingContext, "edit_" + modelName, modelName, options);
});
```

The template has this code in it:

```
{{#each module in modules}}
  <div class="tab-content" {{bind-attr class="module.active:active"}}>
    {{renderModuleEdit module module}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

The problem is that render fails on the test for 'quoteless parameters', even though I'm using `call()` on it, rather than a direct handlebars template syntax. The test is defined in the source on [this line](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.4.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/render.js#L103). The actual test is `options.types[0] !== 'ID'`, and while the options parameter is available in the register helper function (first code block above), and thus I would be able to change the 1<sup>st</sup> type away from `'ID'`, I'm not sure what I can change it *to* that wouldn't cause something else to subtly break later. The error message comes through as:

> Uncaught Error: Using a quoteless parameter with {{render}} is deprecated. Please update to quoted usage '{{render "edit_Intro"}}.

As I am not using `{{render edit_Intro}}` to make this call, I have no idea how to correct this. If I change the template code to `{{renderModuleEdit 'module' 'module'}}`, then the parameters to my renderModuleEdit come through as strings of `'module'` rather than the model instance I need.

I feel like I have no understanding of what this test is actually for and what the 'quoteless' vs 'quoted' parameters even mean. Can someone explain this? Is there a way around this deprecation warning for calling render from a registered bound handlebars helper like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty solution, but working for now:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('renderModuleEdit', function(callingContext, module, options) {
  options.types[0] = "STRING";  // FIXME: hack

  var modelName = callingContext.get('type').get('modelName');
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.render.call(callingContext, "edit_" + modelName,     modelName, options);
});
```

I also, wasn't able to find a proper fix yet :-/

Comment: Yeah, I debugged into the `helpers.render` call and found that `"STRING"` is one of the other accepted properties. I did not find all the corners of ember code where those options get passed, so I would really hate to inadvertently impact something else.